# System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null with Unit tests

Tags: c#, sql-server, null, connection-string

When I'm trying to do unit tests on my solution (my solution contains 5 layers, DAO, Utilities, ENTITIES, UI, DB), in Utilites there is a class who creates a conection between DATABASE and the solution, it name is "CONEXION.cs"
When I do this:

```
[TestClass]
public class CONSULTARPERFILES
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CONSULTARPERFIL()
    {
        var a = new PERFILESNEGOCIO();

        var b = a.CONSULTARLISTADOPERFILES();

        Assert.IsTrue(true,"No encontrado");
    }
}
```

I get a null reference here `var b = a.CONSULTARLISTADOPERFILES();` Debugging project, I found this:

```
public class CONEXION
{
    public string CadenaConexion()
    {
        return WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ConnectionString;

    }        
}
```

My problem is this: `return WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ConnectionString;`

And I used this too:  `return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CadenaConexion"].ToString();`

This is my ConnectionString that is in my Web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CadenaConexion" connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-0KMO6KG3;Initial Catalog=Serviteca;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

how can I solved it? please

Comment: In order to use connection strings in unit tests, you'll need to create a separate app.config file inside the unit test project and copy the connection strings into it. It won't automatically pull from your web project. May not be a good idea though. We tend to avoid hitting an actual DB inside unit tests as that is usually an indicator that the test is too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use connection strings in unit tests, you'll need to create a separate app.config file inside the unit test project and copy the connection strings into it. It won't automatically pull from your web project.

Example Solution:

- MyWebProject

  - web.config (with connection string)
- MyUnitTestProject

  - app.config (with connection string)

Code running in **MyUnitTestProject** will pull configurations (connection strings, app settings, etc) from the app.config **local** to that project, not from web.config

Side note: Making DB calls inside a unit test is usually not a good idea. We tend to avoid hitting an actual DB inside unit tests as that is usually an indicator that the test is too big. It also doesn't work well when setting up CI/CD pipelines as they may not have access to your local dev database.

Comment: My UnitTestProject use my WebProject, and a Class from my WebProject uses the web.config to connect DB. Might I change it too=